# Convert characters to dates in a panel data set

Tags: r, data-cleaning, panel-data

I am downloading and using the following panel data,

```
# load / install package 
library(rsdmx)
library(dplyr)


# Total 
Assets.PIT <- readSDMX("http://widukind-api.cepremap.org/api/v1/sdmx/IMF/data/IFS/..Q.BFPA-BP6-USD")
Assets.PIT <- as.data.frame(Assets.PIT)
names(Assets.PIT)[10]<-"A.PI.T"
names(Assets.PIT)[6]<-"Code"
AP<-Assets.PIT[c("WIDUKIND_NAME","Code","TIME_PERIOD","A.PI.T")]
AP<-rename(AP, Country=WIDUKIND_NAME, Year=TIME_PERIOD)
```

My goal is to convert the column vector `Year` in the dataframe `AP` into a vector of class `dates`. In other words, I want R to understand the time series part of my panel data. For your information, I have quarterly data, with unbalanced date range across cross sections (in my case countries).

```
head(AP$Year)
[1] "2008-Q2" "2008-Q3" "2008-Q4" "2009-Q1" "2009-Q2" "2009-Q3"
```

Or,

```
AP$Year<-as.factor(AP$Year)
head(AP$Year)
[1] 2008-Q2 2008-Q3 2008-Q4 2009-Q1 2009-Q2 2009-Q3
264 Levels: 1950-Q1 1950-Q2 1950-Q3 1950-Q4 1951-Q1 1951-Q2 1951-Q3 1951-Q4 1952-Q1 1952-Q2 1952-Q3 ... 2015-Q4
```

Is there any easy solution to convert these character dates into time-series dates?

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste(substr(AP$Year,1,4),3*(as.integer(substr(AP$Year,7,7))),"01",sep="-"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`library(zoo) 
as.Date(as.yearqtr(AP$year, format ='%YQ-%q'))`

This should do it.

Comment: Do I need to install a package ? because R cannot find the `as.yearqtr` function.

Comment: Oh yes sorry that's the library 'zoo'